# Doctrine update issue in Symfony2

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I wrote some classes and generate related tables onto DB with `php app/console doctrine:generate:entities` 
Suddenly I understand that I've done something wrong and I've changed something into that classes: Have three classes (A,B,C) where A was connected to B and C is stand alone (for now)) but my schema have to connect A to C. So I modify all classes in a consistent manner and launched `php app/console doctrine:schema:update --force`.

With big surprise, I notice that onto DB no changes were happened!
How could this be possible? Have doctrine a file that he cached something or similar?

P.S.: Relationships between entities are many-to-many

Comment: Doctrine can only make changes it can reproduce from your current entities, like a newly added field. There is no way it can detect a deleted field or a foreign key not existing anymore. These changes have to be done manually.

Comment: @Sgoettschkes Are you sure that there isn't a file where I can go, delete some lines and launch again command?

Answer (score 0):

If you change some lines, you can see which requests will be executed by typing :

```
doctrine:schema:update --dump-sql
```

If doctrine doesn't see your modifications, try restarting apache, or cleaning APC cache. It did the trick for me the last time I had this weird bug.
But doctrine will see if you delete or add a field, of course !

Comment: I've alredy follow that steps but dind't get any result.

Comment: Check your annotations synthax. I already had some troubles because I wrote /* instead of /** at the beginning of annotations.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to generate a new database using the updated entities to check if they are correct? An easy way of doing this, is to change the database name on the `parameters.ini` file and run again the console commands that generate the database:

```
app/console doctrine:database:create
app/console doctrine:schema:create
```

If the new database is incorrect there is something wrong with your entities. How do you have them defined (YAML, XML or Annotations)? I use YAML and sometimes the `doctrine:generate:entities` operation doesn't work well. When this happens I have to delete my PHP entities and run the command again.

Other than that, check the [Doctrine Documentation](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/2.1/reference/association-mapping.html) and make sure that you are defining your associations correctly following the rules of the owning and inverse sides.

Comment: Your suggestion is nice but I suppose that I don't have to run again those command against a new database. This because I remove an association (no data inserted, of course) and relationship's table is still there ...

Comment: Yes, this is just a quick way to debug your entities. That's why I suggested creating a new database.

Comment: I've done but nothing happens, as predictable ... Maybe i've got a typo or something like this... I'll investigate.